# Change of variable in multivariate integral, from one variable to two

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I remember I learned how to do the inverse of this, but I'm looking two things, one is the right way for the next change of variable, second the demonstration.

Z function give the third axis in function of x and y

$$Z(x, y)$$

We travel the space so we have two T (travel) functions who tell the current x/y coords:

$$x = T_x(t)$$
$$y = T_y(t)$$

The integral on time:

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} f(T_x, T_y, Z(T_x, T_y)) \,dt$$

I want to change the variable from dt to dx and dy.

From what I remember, because I didn't learn very well this years ago, if one variable can be written in other we have this:

$$dt(x, y)=\frac{\partial dt}{\partial dx}dx+\frac{\partial dy}{\partial dy}dx$$

Which could lead to:

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{f(T_x, T_y, Z(T_x, T_y))}{\frac{\partial dx}{\partial dt}}dx+\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \frac{f(T_x, T_y, Z(T_x, T_y))}{\frac{\partial dy}{\partial dt}}dy$$

But, even if that is right, I would not have idea why....

If someone ask when this is useful, this comes from other system, and the speed is in function of Z, that means if you have $dx/dt$ is something that can be replaced with a function that does not have time as a variable and you only need to integrate on x/y.

Thx!

Comment: Do you have the demonstration of it there? I would appreciate if you can describe the logic of every step than post the equations. I know if I do it, and test with a equation I'll get the same result, but is not the same to be able to understand the chain rule. Other part I get confused on it is the directions too, justify that in the limit we are to express the change in all directions just looking to x/y changes, at least with no limit is not enough check only that two.